# One-to-Many Unidirectional Parent-Child ID Cascade Save

Tags: java, hibernate, parent-child, one-to-many

When trying to save an ID from my parent class into a child class, I keep getting the error
"ERROR - Field 'parent_id' doesn't have a default value"

I have tried all types of mappings. I am using annotations.

Any help on this would be appreciated

Parent:

```
      @Id
      @Column(name="id")
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
      private long id;
      @Column(name="description")
      private String description;
      @OneToMany
      @Cascade(value= {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE})
      @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
      private List<Child> children;
```

Child:

```
  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;
  @Column(name="description")
  private String description;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "When trying to save an ID from my parent class into a child class". Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must have something wrong somewhere else because those mappings will work the way they are. They could be better, but they'll work. Specifically, all the `@Column` annotations are redundant and unnecessary, and as non sequitor noted, you should use the cascade property of JPA's `@OneToMany` instead of Hibernate's `@Cascade`. I've created a [runnable example](https://github.com/zzantozz/testbed/tree/master/hibernate-unidirectional-one-to-many-with-join-column) with the cleaned-up version of what you posted. If you have git and maven, you can run it with:

```
git clone git://github.com/zzantozz/testbed tmp
cd tmp
mvn -q compile exec:java \
    -Dexec.mainClass=rds.hibernate.UnidirectionalManyToOneJoinColumn \
    -pl hibernate-unidirectional-one-to-many-with-join-column
```

It creates a parent with two children, saves them, and then loads them and prints out the graph. The output is:

```
Creating parent with two children
Loading saved parent
Parent{description='parent', children=[Child{description='child 2'}, Child{description='child 1'}]}
```

Answer (score 20):

A late addition in case anyone ever runs into the same issue.

This entity here, when persisted using Hibernate 4.1.8, *will* cascade the `FieldChange`entities, but will *not* fill the join column:

```
@Entity
public class Event {

    //ID and other fields here

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
    private List<FieldChange<?>> fields = new ArrayList<FieldChange<?>>();

 }
```

Neither does the  insert statement set the `event_id` column, nor does it update the inserted entity after the fact - the `event_id` remains null and the relation is lost.

If, however, the `@JoinColumn` definition is changed like this:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "event_id", nullable = false)
```

, then the insert statement includes the `event_id` column like it should, and all is well.

This may only be a regression in this particular version of Hibernate, but maybe it helps someone.

Comment: I was really scratching my head over this problem and changing `@JoinColumn(name = "event_id")` to `@JoinColumn(name = "event_id", nullable = false)` solved the problem.

Answer (score 9):

In your case JPA provider to persist child object with its parent perform at least three queries on db. First two persist the objects by its own. The last one
update child object with the foreign key referencing parent. The second query fail because you have a NOT NULL constraint on the foreign key column. You have three options:

1. Remove NOT NULL constraint on foreign key in the child entity
2. Use bidirectional relationship
3. Change JPA provider to one which supports such cases.

Comment: Option 1 fixed this problem for me using EclipseLink 2.5.1 Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change your `@OneToMany` to `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)` use JPA rather than the Hibernate extensions

Comment: While certainly a valid suggestion, that doesn't exactly answer OP's question.

Comment: Absolutely correct ChssPly76 I assumed that his use of the extensions here were unfounded seeing that the `parent_id` is not being propagated correctly. His annotations all look correct beside the changes I suggested. What do you think is going on given the lack of info from the OP?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `@JoinColumn annotation` needs a `referencedColumnName` assigned.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
```

Comment: referencedColumnName isn't needed in the typical case of creating a foreign key referencing a primary key. From the docs: "Default (only applies if single join column is being used): The same name as the primary key column of the referenced table."

Answer (score 0):

For **Unidirectional Mapping**

Your child table should have 1 column for foreign key (parent_id).

Add 1 more filed in child entity to set **parent_id** before saving, like below.

```
class Child {
 
  //other fields

   @Column(name = "Id")
    private int parentId;
}
```

then you save parent object

```
Parent createdParent = parentRepository.save(parent);
```

returned createdParent contains auto generated *Parent ID* Use it for setting above parentId field inside Child entity. like below.

```
child.setParentId(createdParent.getId());
```

then save child entity, like.

```
 childRepository.save(child);
```